# Can't access my shared server with SSH key

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, putty, domain-server

I have a shared Linux server from godaddy. I want to connect my shared server with `ssh key` and `PuTTY` from Ubuntu so I can access the server terminal but unfortunately I can't access it.
It shows

```
"server unexpectedly closed network connection putty"
```

I can access my localhost.I also set my `id_rsa.pub`. I tried these commands.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

I want to know, Should I set up anything in my shared server that will help to connect with my Linux server. If yes, what to do? i already tried with `ip-address`,`username`,`passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `service sshd start`, before trying to connect?

There is also copying ssh key from remote host, this is achieve by

```
 ssh-copy-id -l remote-user remote-host
```

edit (as per suggestion) :

- during first ssh-copy-id, you will have to provide password, and allow password authentication.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that he must enable password authentication for copying the public key over ssh... For later pubkey authentication.

Comment: i tried(`ssh-copy-id  user@host-name`) but it showing
`/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`